# Why do websites which "store" money not show the actual currency, but as tokens/credits etc.?

Tags: internet, gambling, currency

I've seen some sites which you give money to (like pokerstars, bet365) but unlike those sites, they display the money as Tokens/Credits. One such site is woduels, their currency is WD tokens.

Is there a problem with showing the currency (like in US dollars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a well-known industrial fact that people are much less risk-averse with arbitrary tokens than they are with money. Even changing the representation of the exact some money from physical cash to a number in a bank account [has this effect](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/credit-cards-make-you-spend-more/).

There are likely other reasons or useful side effects to this practise, as alluded in [another answer to your question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/32694/4657) and in [the answers to this Economics SE question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/481/tokens-vs-money), but this is the most consistently stated reason for the use of value tokens rather than showing a currency value.

There are certainly no general laws forbidding a display of currency value in an account, as this is done regularly for all matter of services, from public transport to gambling websites to financial trading to education institutions.

Answer (score 0):

The only real answer is "because those sites choose to do it that way". Why do they so choose? perhaps because it allows them to change the price of a token at any point without needing to alter the costs of their various services or offers, which remain costing X tokens for Y service. It also allows them to price tokens in various currencies without needing to follow any official rate chart. And since they need only give a user's balance in tokens, not in dollars, pounds, yen or whatever, they can more easily declare that tokens are not refundable. Or they may just think it sounds cooler.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the answer!